# Output Base URL in root.phtml

Tags: magento2, template

my root.phtml looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $htmlAttributes ?>>
    <head <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $headAttributes ?>>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $requireJs ?>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $headContent ?>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $headAdditional ?>
    </head>
    <body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $loaderIcon ?>"}}' <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $bodyAttributes ?>>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $layoutContent ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I output the base URL?

I have tried:

`<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl(); ?>`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work in root.phtml file, recently I had faced the same issue and adjusted to get the base url via php core function: <?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?> and if you need with request URI then you can try <?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have instance of `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in your construct, you can get the base URL using this:

`$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()`

Using object manager (not recommended):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

Comment: I get: "There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."

Comment: If you go to `magento_root/var/report` and find the file with the same error number you will be able to get more info about the error.

Comment: I get Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor::$_storeManager

Comment: It turns out what I was looking for wasn't the base URL, but rather, the theme's URL, which I got using: $this->getViewFileUrl( '/' ); Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: glad you found a solution :)